# Is there a rev matching device?

Tags: rpm, electronics

I understand that rev matching is acquired skill by practicing and driving more. I'd like to know if there was a device you could attach to your car that would detect and notify you if engine rev is match with your transmission (maybe with an audible beep)

A device like that would be very useful for new drivers trying to practice rev matching, because rev matching is very useful when down shifting without stalling like when your going up a hill.

I have a 1.5 Manual Honda Mobilio

Comment: Can you include the year, make, model, and engine size of your vehicle? I'm not aware of an aftermarket system, but I don't race either. Nissan had a system on the 370z called SynchroRev Match where the ECM would engage the throttle during a downshift.

Comment: @DavidWinslow Thanks David! I am aware of a few cars doing automatic rev matching but I am wondering if there is one that would only assist and notify you if your rev is high enough already to let go of the clutch. This is useful for learning.

Comment: If you have the knowledge, get a bluetooth obd2 adapter, either an old laptop, netbook, android, or iphone, write a program, and start playing.  Of course you could low tech: a cup of water.  Keep the water in the cup and you are driving smoothly.  Watch the first few episodes of Initial D(anime).

Comment: I knew the cup in the water was too familiar. I've watched, but that's pretty messy. but the OBD2 adapter seems like a great choice. I'm a softwre developer and might explore that soon. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Anyone willing to submit an answer?

Comment: Will the OBD2 adapter tell you what gear you're in? If so, that sounds like a workable solution, but AFAIK positive gear indication is only available for automatic transmissions.

Comment: That may take some experimentation. The bt obd2 adapter with various different apps to find all info. Torque being one. They might not all be free.

Comment: Alternate method for the water, a water bottle with lines filled with a dark oil (used motor oil?). Keep the cap on.

Comment: There's an 80's movie, license to drive?  Kid is taking his driving test.  Instructor puts his coffee on the dash and says if he spills the coffee, he fails. Car was a stick, made him stop on a decently steep hill.

Comment: @TMN 06+? Subaru manual transmissions have a gear indicator on the instrument cluster so it's possible if the manufacturer put sensors in the case. DSGs do this as well though they're not traditional manual transmissions

Answer (score 0):

There are companies that make throttle blippers.  Supposidly they have versions for electronic and cable throttles.

[here's one for motorcycle](https://www.proshift.com/shop/bike-system/dbs-bike-engine/)

[And one for a car](https://www.auto-blip.com/)